# Input tag is not getteng attach inside the div correctly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my javascript function I am getting one div.

my div is

```
var divDetails = args.val;
```

where `divDetails = "<div id="chart_line" style="width:26%; background-color: lightblue;"></div>"`

Now I have to add one input tag so Here I am declearing

```
var input = '<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="\
                    url: "JSON/combobox_data1.json",\
                    method: "get",\
                    valueField: "id",\
                    textField: "text",\
                    panelWidth: 350,\
                    multiple:true,\
                    label: "Language:",\
                    labelPosition: "top"\
                    >';
```

My input is comming correctly.

```
"<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="                    url: "JSON/combobox_data1.json",                    method: "get",                    valueField: "id",                    textField: "text",                    panelWidth: 350,                    multiple:true,                    label: "Language:",                    labelPosition: "top"                    >"
```

Now When I am adding this input to the div `divDetails.innerHTML = input` I am getting this

```
"<div id="chart_line" style="width:26%; background-color: lightblue;"><input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="                    url: " json="" combobox_data1.json",="" method:="" "get",="" valuefield:="" "id",="" textfield:="" "text",="" panelwidth:="" 350,="" multiple:true,="" label:="" "language:",="" labelposition:="" "top"=""></div>"
```

Which is wrong. What I suppose to get is

```
"<div id="chart_line" style="width:26%; background-color: lightblue;"> 
       <input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="url: 'JSON/combobox_data1.json',method: 'get',valueField: 'id',textField: 'text',panelWidth: 350,multiple:true,label: 'Language:',labelPosition: 'top'"> 
    </div>"
```

Can You please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: use appendChild() [check](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Comment: Change `"` to `'` in your `input data-options`.

Comment: @Durga I am getting this error on divDetails.appendChild(input).` Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: @Oen44 IS this correct `var input = '<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="\
                    url: 'JSON/combobox_data1.json',\
                    method: 'get',\
                    valueField: 'id',\
                    textField: 'text',\
                    panelWidth: 350,\
                    multiple:true,\
                    label: 'Language:',\
                    labelPosition: 'top'\
                    >';`

Comment: Do you have a codepen example?

Comment: @David No, it's not. Doing what you are trying to do is very bad... Use multiple `data` instead.

Comment: @Win Let me try to create a codePan

Comment: @Oen44 Any example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't do such thing as putting entire Ajax into `data` attribute. You shouldn't even put that there anyway. But if you actually have to do that, then do it properly. Use multiple `data` attributes instead of one.

## JavaScript

```js
var input = document.createElement('input');

input.setAttribute('data-url', "JSON/combobox_data1.json");
input.setAttribute('data-method', "GET");
input.setAttribute('data-value', "id");
input.setAttribute('data-text', "text");
input.setAttribute('data-panel', "350");
input.setAttribute('data-multiple', "true");
input.setAttribute('data-label', "Language:");
input.setAttribute('data-position', "top");

document.getElementById('div').appendChild(input);

console.log(input.getAttribute('data-url'));
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

## jQuery

```js
$('<input/>', {
  data: {
    url: "JSON/combobox_data1.json",
    method: "GET"
    /* ... */
  }
}).appendTo('#div');

console.log($('input').data('url'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: But All my values  I need this under `data-option` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am using this so I need these values under `data-options` http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Combo&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=&sort=

Comment: That's very bad idea, don't do that, think of better solution.

Comment: YA, I am thinking I have so dynamic combobox so I was thinking to use those API's but `data-option` causing issue. Let me think some way